# Software license : ML-LPL in commercial. AR library

Tags: windows-phone-7, licensing

I'm facing problem with understanding Microsoft ML-LPL license http://gart.codeplex.com/license

After riding it I'm still unable to understand if it can be used in commercial project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MS-LPL is essentially the MS-PL, where the extra L means "Limited", and has the extra condition that the projects must be for the Windows platform:

> 3 (F) Platform Limitation- The licenses granted in sections 2(A) & 2(B) extend only to the software or derivative works that you create
>   that run on a Microsoft Windows operating system product.

And MS-PL is [allowed for commercial use](http://www.tldrlegal.com/license/microsoft-public-license-%28ms-pl%29), so aslong as your project is for the Windows platform it should be fine.